# Oracle to redshift query migration

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift

I am trying to transition from Oracle to redshift and got stuck with this function conversion. Can someone help me with this?

Oracle: `trunc(to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}', 'YYYYMMDD')-6, 'DAY')`

RedShift: ?

Comment: `date_trunc()`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting the date without the time part.
In Redshift, you can simply use 
'{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}' :: date - 6
or 
to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}', 'YYYYMMDD')-6